# Sparse linear differential equation solving Matlab vs Python

Tags: python, matlab, sparse-matrix, equation

I am currently working on a project that involves huge matrix. The size is around 500 000 by 500 000 but they are very sparse with a density of around 0.000025 so about 6-6.5 millions non-zero elements only. Here is my problem, i need to solve the linear equation Ax = B with A being the 500k by 500k matrix and B being a vector, multiple time, with only B changing. I starting working on this project using someone else code which was done in Matlab and i wanted to implement it in python because i though it would be faster (am i wrong in thinking that? is Matlab faster for solving these type of equation?) Heres the thing... when im using their script (in Matlab) doing A\B takes about 110 seconds which seems really fast to me. But when i try using SciPy sparse solving to solve the same system it just doesn't work as fast or in fact not at all, i always end up cancelling the script because it is too long.

So basically, is using A\B in Matlab just too good or am i doing something wrong? Could it be because of memory? As in python needs to create something in between steps and i run out of place so it just crash or something?

Thanks in advance!

PS : If you are thinking about suggesting LU decomposition for futur iteration, i am already planning on doing this, i just want to know what is up with directly solving it using SciPy sparse solve.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+is+matlab+faster+than+python+is%3Aq)

Comment: Scipy's sparse code isn't always the most well-optimized. MKL's sparse solver is a lot faster although it's annoying to get running right with python objects.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, i ended up using : https://github.com/haasad/PyPardisoProject which turned out faster than my matlab script! But later in the code a have another solve needed for Ax = B with A and B being sparse matrix of size around 30k by 30k. Matlab seems faster for this step still compared to PyPardiso, any idea what i could use to solve Ax =  B with A and B being matrix?